# Generalized Newtype Deriving

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad, deriving, newtype

Haskell can derive the instance for `MonadState s` in `T1` below but not in `T2` which is however a very similar type. In which way should I modify the code for `T2` so that the instance for `MonadState s` can be automatically derived?

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.State

newtype T1 r s a = 
  T1 { runT1 :: ReaderT r (State s) a }
  deriving (Monad, MonadReader r, MonadState s)

newtype T2 r s a = 
  T2 { runT2 :: StateT r (State s) a }
  deriving (Monad, MonadState r, MonadState s)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't have a type have two instances for `MonadState`.  This is because `MonadState` is defined as

```
class Monad m => MonadState s m | m -> s where
    get :: m s
    set :: s -> m ()
    state :: (s -> (a, s)) -> m a
```

The key part is the `| m -> s`.  This requires the extension `FunctionalDependencies`, and states that for any `m`, we automatically know the associated `s`.  This means that for any given `m`, there can only be *one* choice for `s` that is valid.  So you can't have it work for both `MonadState r m` and `MonadState s m` unless `r ~ s`.  If `r ~ s`, then how would the compiler know which underlying monad for it to apply to?  In this case, I think you'll also find that it'll be much easier to understand and work with the code if you create `get` and `put` functions that have suffixes to indicate which, like `getInner`, `setInner` and `getOuter`, `setOuter`.