# Unable to derive Applicative when combining two monad transformer stacks

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, deriving, newtype

I've written two monads for a domain-specific language I'm developing. The first is `Lang`, which is supposed to include everything needed to parse the language line by line. I knew I would want reader, writer, and state, so I used the `RWS` monad:

```
type LangLog    = [String]
type LangState  = [(String, String)]
type LangConfig = [(String, String)]

newtype Lang a = Lang { unLang :: RWS LangConfig LangLog LangState a }
  deriving
    ( Functor
    , Applicative
    , Monad
    , MonadReader LangConfig
    , MonadWriter LangLog
    , MonadState  LangState
    )
```

The second is `Repl`, which uses [Haskeline](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskeline) to interact with a user:

```
newtype Repl a = Repl { unRepl :: MaybeT (InputT IO) a }
  deriving
    ( Functor
    , Applicative
    , Monad
    , MonadIO
    )
```

Both seem to work individually (they compile and I've played around with their behavior in GHCi), but I've been unable to embed `Lang` into `Repl` to parse lines from the user. The main question is, how can I do that?

More specifically, if I write `Repl` to include `Lang` the way I originally intended:

```
newtype Repl a = Repl { unRepl :: MaybeT (InputT IO) (Lang a) }
  deriving
    ( Functor
    , Applicative
    , Monad
    , MonadIO
    , MonadReader LangConfig
    , MonadWriter LangLog
    , MonadState  LangState
    )
```

It mostly typechecks, but I can't derive `Applicative` (required for `Monad` and all the rest).

Since I'm new to monad transformers and designing REPLs, I've been studying/cargo-culting from [Glambda](https://github.com/goldfirere/glambda)'s `Repl.hs` and `Monad.hs`. I originally picked it because I will try to use GADTs for my expressions too. It includes a couple unfamiliar practices, which I've adopted but am totally open to changing:

- `newtype` + `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` (is this dangerous?)
- `MaybeT` to allow quitting the REPL with `mzero`

Here's my working code so far:

```
{- LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

module Main where

import Control.Monad.RWS.Lazy
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
import System.Console.Haskeline

-- Lang monad for parsing language line by line

type LangLog    = [String]
type LangState  = [(String, String)]
type LangConfig = [(String, String)]

newtype Lang a = Lang { unLang :: RWS LangConfig LangLog LangState a }
  deriving
    ( Functor
    , Applicative
    , Monad
    , MonadReader LangConfig
    , MonadWriter LangLog
    , MonadState  LangState
    )

-- Repl monad for responding to user input

newtype Repl a = Repl { unRepl :: MaybeT (InputT IO) (Lang a) }
  deriving
    ( Functor
    , Applicative
    , Monad
    , MonadIO
    )
```

And a couple attempts to extend it. First, including `Lang` in `Repl` as mentioned above:

```
newtype Repl a = Repl { unRepl :: MaybeT (InputT IO) (Lang a) }
 deriving
   ( Functor
   , Applicative
   )

--     Can't make a derived instance of ‘Functor Repl’
--       (even with cunning newtype deriving):
--       You need DeriveFunctor to derive an instance for this class
--     In the newtype declaration for ‘Repl’
-- 
-- After :set -XDeriveFunctor, it still complains:
-- 
--     Can't make a derived instance of ‘Applicative Repl’
--       (even with cunning newtype deriving):
--       cannot eta-reduce the representation type enough
--     In the newtype declaration for ‘Repl’
```

Next, trying to just use both of them at once:

```
-- Repl around Lang:
-- can't access Lang operations (get, put, ask, tell)
type ReplLang a = Repl (Lang a)

test1 :: ReplLang ()
test1 = do
  liftIO $ putStrLn "can do liftIO here"
  -- but not ask
  return $ return ()

-- Lang around Repl:
-- can't access Repl operations (liftIO, getInputLine)
type LangRepl a = Lang (Repl a)

test2 :: LangRepl ()
test2 = do
  _ <- ask -- can do ask
  -- but not liftIO
  return $ return ()
```

Not shown: I also tried various permutations of `lift` on the `ask` and `putStrLn` calls. Finally, to be sure this isn't an RWS-specific issue I tried writing `Lang` without it:

```
newtype Lang2 a = Lang2
  { unLang2 :: ReaderT LangConfig (WriterT LangLog (State LangState)) a
  }
  deriving
    ( Functor
    , Applicative
    )
```

That gives the same eta-reduce error.

So to recap, the main thing I want to know is how do I combine these two monads? Am I missing an obvious combination of `lift`s, or arranging the transformer stack wrong, or running into some deeper issue?

Here are a couple possibly-related questions I looked at:

- [Tidying up Monads - turning application of a monad transformer into newtype monad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572152/tidying-up-monads-turning-application-of-a-monad-transformer-into-newtype-mona)
- [Generalized Newtype DerivingGeneralized Newtype Deriving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693483/generalized-newtype-deriving)
- [Issue deriving MonadTrans for chained custom monad transformers](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/3mrkwe/issue_deriving_monadtrans_for_chained_custom/)

Update: my hand-wavy understanding of monad transformers was the main problem. Using `RWST` instead of `RWS` so `LangT` can be inserted between `Repl` and `IO` mostly solves it:

```
newtype LangT m a = LangT { unLangT :: RWST LangConfig LangLog LangState m a }
  deriving
    ( Functor
    , Applicative
    , Monad
    , MonadReader LangConfig
    , MonadWriter LangLog
    , MonadState  LangState
    )

type Lang2 a = LangT Identity a

newtype Repl2 a = Repl2 { unRepl2 :: MaybeT (LangT (InputT IO)) a }
  deriving
    ( Functor
    , Applicative
    , Monad
    -- , MonadIO -- ghc: No instance for (MonadIO (LangT (InputT IO)))
    , MonadReader LangConfig
    , MonadWriter LangLog
    , MonadState  LangState
    )
```

The only remaining issue is I need to figure out how to make `Repl2` an instance io `MonadIO`.

Update 2: All good now! Just needed to add `MonadTrans` to the list of instances derived for `LangT`.

Comment: `IO` must be at the bottom of your monad transformer stack because there [is no `IOT` monad transformer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056663/why-is-there-no-io-transformer-in-haskell). Something like `newtype LangT m a = LangT (RWST .. .. .. m a); newtype Repl a = Repl (MaybeT (InputT (LangT IO)) a)` might work for you.

Comment: You're right, thanks! I knew `IO` has to be on the bottom, but for some reason it hadn't occurred to me that the whole stack is linear. I thought you could put another type sort of "off to the side". Will update the question.

Comment: `LangT` needs a `MonadIO m => MonadIO (LangT m)` instance (which can probably be derived) because the `MonadIO m => MonadIO (MaybeT m)` instance requires it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to compose the two monads, one on top of the another. But in general [monads don't compose this way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13034229/1333025). Let's have a look at a simplified version of your case. Let's assume we have just `Maybe` instead of `MaybeT ...` and `Reader` instead of `Lang`. So the type of your monad  would be

```
Maybe (LangConfig -> a)
```

Now if this were a monad, we would have a total [`join`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join) function, which would have type

```
join :: Maybe (LangConfig -> Maybe (LangConfig -> a)) -> Maybe (LangConfig -> a)
```

And here a problem comes: What if the argument is a value `Just f` where

```
f :: LangConfig -> Maybe (LangConfig -> a)
```

and for some input `f` returns `Nothing`? There is no reasonable way how we could construct a meaningful value of `Maybe (LangConfig -> a)` from `Just f`. We need to read the `LangConfig` so that `f` can decide if its output will be `Nothing` or `Just something`, but within `Maybe (LangConfig -> a)` we can either return `Nothing` or read `LangConfig`, not both! So we can't have such a `join` function.

If you carefully look at monad transformers, you see that sometimes there is just one way how to combine two monads, and it's not their naive composition. In particular, both `ReaderT r Maybe a` and `MaybeT (Reader r) a` are isomorphic to `r -> Maybe a`. As we saw earlier, the reverse isn't a monad.

So the solution to your problem is to construct monad transformers instead of monads. You can either have both as monad transformers:

```
newtype LangT m a = Lang { unLang :: RWST LangConfig LangLog LangState m a }
newtype ReplT m a = Repl { unRepl :: MaybeT (InputT m) a }
```

and use them as `LangT (ReplT IO) a` or `ReplT (LangT IO) a` (as described in one of the comments, `IO` always has to be at the bottom of the stack). Or you can have just one of them (the outer one) as a transformer and another as a monad. But as you're using `IO`, the inner monad will have to internally include `IO`.

Note that there is a difference between `LangT (ReplT IO) a` and `ReplT (LangT IO) a`. It's similar to the difference between `StateT s Maybe a` and `MaybeT (State s) a`: If the former fails with `mzero`, neither result nor output state is produed. But in the latter fails with `mzero`, there is no result, but the state will remain available.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm (slowly, finally) starting to get an intuition for this stuff.